# Trouble with @font-face and .ttf file

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I'm trying to use @font-face to implement a font I downloaded online (http://www.losttype.com/font/?name=blanch) and I'm having issues getting it to work on any browser. Here's the sample code I'm using to test the font.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "title">
        <p>THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the css file is:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Blanch;
    src: url(‘BLANCH_CONDENSED.ttf’);
}
.title {
    text-align:center;
    font-family: Blanch, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:white;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}
```

I only have the .ttf file. Can someone explain why this isn't working?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267415/using-true-type-fonts-in-web-applications

Comment: What is your file/directory structure ?

Comment: I have the html file in the same folder as main.css. Right now, I'm just using the code above in two separate files to try and get the font working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the construct `url(‘BLANCH_CONDENSED.ttf’)`, the ‘smart’ single quotes must be replaced by Ascii quotes (single or double), e.g. `url('BLANCH_CONDENSED.ttf')`.

You should also use [FontSquirrel webfont generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) or some similar tool to generate different font formats to cover all browsers.

Comment: Once I added all the different font formats, it seemed to work! Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

That .rar that you posted only has .otf files in it, in your CSS file you have a .ttf. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Maybe I ended up posting the wrong link, but I definitely have a ttf.